# android enable access to application only to users who purchased the application

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a html5 Web View Android application which uses php website . How do I enable the use of website only for people who have purchased the application .I was thinking of a combination of getting the users android device id in combination with php mysql generated id and preventing php site access by using a php library that checks if client is a mobile phone .Perhaps even Google application licensing - I don't know how easy is to get around this by recompiling of application ?Maybe even a good way to hide the url inside Android application.

Answer (score 2):

Where do users purchase the application? How do they get access to your website?

If they purchase your app from Google Play, then you should use some form of authentication/authorization that forces them to sign into your website and establish credentials there and on the device.

Please don't use the device id. That's not particularly friendly, and it opens up a security hole. In addition, it's an inconvenience to users who upgrade (or lose) a device.

A username and password should be sufficient security for most situations. If it isn't in your case, then you could also consider establishing an encrypted key on the device after the user first logs into your site. The key could be based on various values that the user would have difficulty reproducing on a different device.

One must consider the tradeoff of securing against undesired access versus the effort involved. How likely is it that users will give away their username and passwords to allow others to use your site? If you secure something too much, nobody will use it.

Comment: Thing I am mostly interested is in getting only users on the site that have purchased the application , I do not want Goole to send me users on my site . I would like to avoid logging in by the user-I do not like doing this myself .